# Need Reglar Expression to find English words in Chinese language

Tags: c#, java, php, javascript, regex

I need reg expression to find the English text from Chinese and add a class for it.

Example:
Input

```
<p>当然，你要学习<a href='#' target='_blank'>“<b>Megento</b>”</a></p>
```

Output Should be:

```
<p>当然，你要学习<a href='#' target='_blank'>“<b><span class="english">Megento</span></b>”</a></p>
```

Comment: You probably mean 'Latin characters' rather than 'English text'.

Comment: Go through that post and learn something from it.

Comment: Your question is too confusing in the way it is. Can u elaborate what you really want.

Comment: It depends on what type of encoding you use. Can you append it?

Comment: I have made the regular expression as `/(<[/\w :/{}%"'=),;.\-]+>)|([\w :/{}%"'=(),.&]+)/g` it worked for me till now.

Answer (score 0):

.NET regular expressions can match based on Unicode character ranges (see *[Unicode Category or Unicode Block: `\p{}`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CategoryOrBlock)*). For example the regex `\p{IsBasicLatin}` will match `x`, but not `Ǝ` (U+018E: Latin Capital Letter Reversed E).

Using this to match the text content of elements is therefore quite possible.

[But don't use regex to parse the HTML itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use an HTML parser to process the HTML and then the regex to look at the text content.